# Special Characters on zsh prompt using oh-my-zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, redhat

I've just started using zsh as my shell, coming from bash. I am on a RedHat Linux Workstation build 6.4. I have all the relevent locales installed but when I move to a zsh prompt and pick any of the themes I have a PS1 that looks like this

```
ââ[name@host] - [~/tars] - [2013-11-05 09:50:26]
ââ[0]
```

I'm not sure what is causing these special characters. Another example:

```
name@host ~/tars Â» echo $PS1                                                                                                                                                                                                    1 âµ
%{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%n%{$fg[green]%}@%m%{$reset_color%} %~ \
$(git_prompt_info)\
%{$fg[red]%}%(!.#.Â»)%{$reset_color%}
```

Is there something I'm missing that I should have installed?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the prompt theme you use you need a font which supports those characters or need to install additional fonts for your terminal, like the [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts) fonts.